# Test NG annotation extension

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have some unstable tests in project with annotation like '@Test(retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class)'(runner-TestNG). In RetryAnalyzer class implemented retry logic.

How to create custom annotation which will extend @Test annotation and will have default value of retryAnalyzer? (@Test(retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class) -> @UnstableTest)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way of doing this.

- Create your custom annotation (`@UnstableTest` in your case)
- Build an implementation of `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` wherein you test the `Method` object that comes in as a parameter for the `transform()` method and see if it has your annotation and if yes, then inject the annotation.

Here's how it can look like :

**The marker annotation which marks flaky tests**

```
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD})
@interface UnstableTest {}
```

**The annotation transformer**

```
public static class UnstableTestInjector implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        if (testMethod == null) {
            return;
        }

        UnstableTest unstableTest = testMethod.getAnnotation(UnstableTest.class);
        if (unstableTest == null) {
            return;
        }
        annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(TryAgain.class);
    }
}
```

Now add this listener using the `<listeners>` tag.

That should do.